# Is there any Careers CV API available?

Tags: support

Is there any API for the CV service of Careers (careers.stackoverflow.com)?

My requirements are simple, I just need a way to access the data of a given CV to propose an alternative view.

Comment: There is no such thing at this time. Kevin would be able to tell you if there are future plans for such a thing, though I'm kind of doubtful that it would be created.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know Kevin yet. How to contact him?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Career's API, nor are there any plans for one currently.

There has been something of an [export capacity](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/28375/should-careers-stackoverflow-com-support-hresume/32216#32216) for awhile, in the form of the [hResume microformat](http://microformats.org/wiki/hresume).

Comment: That would have been enough. Why it has been removed?

Comment: @Pierre 303 - hResume is still supported for public resumes.  Its just not really an "API," more markup/export really.

Comment: OK got it. The data is actually encoded right in the HTML output. Thanks to you, I learnt something new today! Thanks